# Why won't the margin show up in my code

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to make a website where there is a picture and underneath it have a margin where there is information with a background colour. When I try to run the code I created it will not show the margin and therefore be useless. Does anyone know how I would fix this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<html>
<style>
<head>

img {
    padding:0; margin:0;
}

div {
     font-size: 55px;
     font-family: Impact;
     color: #000066;
}

h1 {
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    background-color: red;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<img src="picmine.jpg" width="1440" height="500" style="position: absolute; top:0px; left:1px"/>

<div style="position: absolute; top:100px; left:350px"><center>Brantley and Brennan's Creations</div></center>

<h1><center>Love of Technology</h1></center>

</body>
```

Comment: If this is your exact code, it's invalid - the style element must be nested inside a body or head tag.

Comment: What do you mean? Is style supposed to be underneath the body

Comment: Even without <head> tags, when I try your code above with an image on my desktop that images shows. Make sure your src="" path is correct.

Comment: style tags are supposed to go between head tags. https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tag_style.asp

Comment: @Kobbe         The image is always shown. The margin just doesn't show up

Comment: You're missing the `}` to close the `div` styles

Comment: @MichaelCoker.   Thanks a lot. That worked. It was just an editing mistake

Comment: @Kg123 you're welcome

Comment: Actually, to look at it, all of your markup is invalid. Don't use the center tag, and if you do, the tags need to the closed in the reverse order they are opened (so `<div>` - `<center>` - `</center>` - `</div>`)

Comment: It's the position absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your style tags are not in the right order. They should be inside the head tags like this:

```
<head>
 <style>
  //css
 </style>
</head>
```